# Reinstall macOS after having Linux

Tags: macos, high-sierra, startup, install

I installed Ubuntu on a 2010 Macbook, just to try it out. I now want to go back to either Sierra o High Sierra.

I created Install UBS sticks and I tried to boot from them by holding the Option Key. When I do that, a screen appears with the "typical" macOS icons for a HHD and a Removable Disc (orange icon). If I choose the HDD icon it eventually boots Ubuntu. If I choose the Instal USB drive, the screen goes apple grey with a "no parking" sign in a darker shade of grey (...).

I tried every combination I found on internet (cmd+R, cmd+option+R, cmd+option+shift+R, and some other maybe) but nothing makes the disk utility to pop up.

As an additional info, when I boot up, the typical Apple chime is there but no apple logo whatsoever...

Is there hope for something?

Comment: Created USB boot sticks *how*?

Comment: I don't find the link I used, but it goes somehow like this https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/bootable-mac-install-drive-3575875/

Comment: That machine does not support network boot. It may not have a recovery partition.  https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/restore-mac-without-recovery-3636668/

Comment: This machine should have come with a DVD. It was shipped with: Original OS Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D2162)
Later OS Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F2108), 10.7.2 (11C74)  You may order Snow Leopard from apple see: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard  be sure to verify with apple what version of Snow Leopard Apple is selling.  There is a chance you machine came with 10.7, but I'd suspect it would have a recovery partition if it did.

Comment: @historystamp: Your comment referring to "network boot" may not be true. See the Apple website: [Computers that can be upgraded to use OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313)

Comment: @historystamp: The picture in your link for Snow Leopard show version 10.6. If the MacBook minimum version for OS X is 10.6.3, then the DVD may not contain the hardware drivers for this model Mac.

Comment: @David Anderson, I had a chat with Apple Support and the disc ships as version 10.6.1 even though it says 10.6 at that URL. Still might be an issue as you mentioned.

Comment: @David Anderson.  Good you pointed that out, but the user would have had to already installed the firmware update and the user is failing with network boot.  "Download and install an updated EFI Firmware ROM for these computers to use the OS X Internet Recovery feature"

Comment: Well, there is ebay.  Let the buyer be cautious.  https://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-Mac-OS-X-Snow-leopard-10-6-3-Factory-Reset-Install-DVD-New-Unopened/323720175905?epid=1048338447&hash=item4b5f39e121:g:uOMAAOSw-YVcfE0x  Whether or not your machine would boot with 10.6.3 is for you to determina.

Comment: @FelixHauser  I'd say that you do not have the correct version of macOS on the USB drive.  "If I choose the Instal USB drive, the screen goes apple grey with a "no parking" sign in a darker shade of grey (...)."  Where did you find the download?

Comment: @FelixHauser Apple is still selling 10.7.  It comes as a download.  I have no experience converting the download to boot from a usb drive.  https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion

Comment: @FelixHauser If you know your machine's serial number, you can find more information.  Best for older machines.  Note, serial number is sent in the clear.
"A serial number is a unique, identifying number or group of numbers and letters assigned to an individual piece of hardware or software. It's used for various things depending on the product / brand but what is your Mac's serial number for and more importantly... what is it hiding and what can it do for you ?"
http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com/Desktop/index.php

Comment: @historystamp: If you look closely at your link for 10.7, you will see that the Mac needs to have 10.6.6 to 10.6.8 already installed. In other words, the purchase is an upgrade and can not be used for a clean install. Since the upgrade to El Capitan is free, I believe such a purchase would be a waste of money.